# Texts in SVG are shown on top of each other

Tags: xml, svg, text, styling

I've got a problem with the following code:

```html
<svg viewBox="100 0 600 600" 
    width="100%" height="100%" 
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <style>
   .draw {stroke-dasharray: 10; animation: dashdraw 4s linear infinite;}
   @keyframes dashdraw {to {stroke-dashoffset: 200;}}
 </style> 

 <g>
  <title>This is our Hub</title>
  <a xlink:href="#nds"><ellipse id="hub_nds" ry="100" rx="100" cy="300" cx="400" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/></a>
  <a xlink:href="#os"><ellipse id="hub_os" ry="50" rx="50" cy="500" cx="400" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/></a>
  <a xlink:href="#h"><ellipse id="hub_h" ry="50" rx="50" cy="200" cx="200" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/></a>
  <a xlink:href="#ol"><ellipse id="hub_ol" ry="50" rx="50" cy="400" cx="200" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/></a>
  <a xlink:href="#hi"><ellipse id="hub_hi" ry="50" rx="50" cy="200" cx="600" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/></a>
  <a xlink:href="#fields-ueberschrift28"><ellipse id="hub_top" stroke-dasharray="5,5" ry="50" rx="50" cy="100" cx="400" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/></a>
  <a xlink:href="#fields-ueberschrift28"><ellipse id="hub_btm" stroke-dasharray="5,5" ry="50" rx="50" cy="400" cx="600" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/></a>

  <a xlink:href="#nds" style="font-weight: normal;"><text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="inherit" font-size="20" stroke-width="0" id="svg_24" y="296" x="316.07422" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">This is our</text>
  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="inherit" color="inherit" font-size="20" stroke-width="0" id="svg_28" y="323" x="333.29297" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">Main hub</text></a>
  <a xlink:href="#h" style="font-weight: normal;"><text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="inherit" font-size="16" stroke-width="0" id="svg_29" y="205" x="165" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">Here is Hub 1</text></a>
  <a xlink:href="#hi" style="font-weight: normal;"><text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="inherit" font-size="16" stroke-width="0" id="svg_30" y="205" x="560" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">Here is Hub 2</text></a>
  <a xlink:href="#ol" style="font-weight: normal;"><text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="inherit" font-size="16" stroke-width="0" id="svg_31" y="406" x="162" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">Here is Hub 3</text></a>
  <a xlink:href="#os" style="font-weight: normal;"><text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="inherit" font-size="16" stroke-width="0" id="svg_32" y="505" x="361.30469" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">Os</text></a>

  <line id="line1_btm" class="draw" transform="rotate(-180 520.351 365)" stroke-dasharray="5,5" stroke="#000" y2="380" x2="554.80685" y1="350" x1="485.8947" fill="none"/>
  <line id="line2_btm" class="draw" stroke-dasharray="5,5" stroke="#000" y2="381.82648" x2="554.35023" y1="351.82648" x1="485.43808" fill="none"/>

  <line id="line1_h" class="draw" x2="245.89744" y2="219.82051" y1="251.61538" x1="312.30769" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <line id="line2_h" class="draw" x1="245.44082" y1="221.64699" y2="253.44186" x2="311.85107" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>

  <line id="line1_ol" class="draw" transform="rotate(-45 279.487 365)" stroke="#000" y2="379.56228" x2="313.94325" y1="350.43772" x1="245.03111" fill="none"/>
  <line id="line2_ol" class="draw" transform="rotate(-45 279.487 365)" stroke="#000" y1="377.7358" x1="313.48663" y2="348.61124" x2="246" fill="none"/>

  <line id="line1_hi" class="draw" transform="rotate(135 520.769 236)" y1="252" x1="553.97436" y2="220" x2="487.5641" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <line id="line2_hi" class="draw" transform="rotate(135 521.226 237.826)" y2="253.82648" x2="554.43098" y1="221.82648" x1="488.02072" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>

  <line id="line1_top" class="draw" stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" y2="200.32547" x2="399.35484" y1="150" x1="399.35484" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <line id="line2_top" class="draw" transform="rotate(180 401.29 175.163)" stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" y2="200.32547" x2="401.29032" y1="150" x1="401.29032" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
 
  <line id="line1_os" class="draw" stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" y2="449.99974" x2="399.35484" y1="399.67426" x1="399.35484" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <line id="line2_os" class="draw" transform="rotate(180 401.29 424.839)" stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" y2="449.99974" x2="401.29032" y1="399.67426" x1="401.29032" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

It is supposed to show some kind of network, a big circle in the middle with several other circles around it, connected by lines. On my Computers and smart phones this works just as intended.

I've heard from a few users though, that the text in those circles sometimes break at apparently random positions and "start again" at the beginning of the word, making the word unreadable. As if it's showing two lines of text on top of each other. This happens to different text elements in the code, so there must be something wrong with it.

As I'm definitely not a programmer, I have no idea how to fix this, especially since i can't reproduce the problem. The code was produced by some online svg-converter and I just customized it a bit to my needs. So I wouldn't be surprised if there's a "smoother" way to do this. :D

Can anyone help me out and show me where the code might have problems?

Thanks!

Comment: What devices are those users using? What operating systems? What browser versions?

Comment: @RobertLongson This is tricky, as I don't have that kind of information. They seem to be on mobile, but apparently not all of them.

Comment: Not sure we can help then. Good luck.

Comment: AFAIK you need to do the maths for font sizes and positions before writing into SVG. The SVG renderer does not even do the word wrap in text blocks for you.